# Как узнать сколько осталось до выполнения кода в таймере?

Tags: java, java-timer

С помощью таймера я удаляю объект из коллекции через 1 секунду

```
for (Iterator<Ball> i = bList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Ball item = i.next();
            if (item.isDead == true) {
                Timer timer = new Timer(TimerDelay, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        bList.remove(item);
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            }
        }
```

Мне нужно делать объект все более красным чем ближе он к удалению.
Цвет планирую задавать так:

```
public Color getBallColor(float CurrentTime) {
    float maxDelay = 1000;

    CurrentTime = CurrentTime < maxDelay ? CurrentTime : maxDelay;

    float H = (CurrentTime/maxDelay) * 0.38f;
    float S = 0.98f;
    float B = 0.95f;

    return Color.getHSBColor(H, S, B);
}
```

И если `maxDelay` известен мне сразу (1 Секунда), то вот `CurrentTime` совершенно не известен. Складывается вопрос: "Как узнать сколько осталось до выполнения кода в таймере?"

Comment: Вероятно, нет такой абстракции, как промежуточное значение таймера. Вам стоит запустить повторяющийся счётчик с меньшим интервалом, для получения промежуточных событий-итераций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вероятно, нет такой абстракции, как промежуточное значение таймера. Вам стоит запустить повторяющийся счётчик с меньшим интервалом, для получения промежуточных событий-итераций.

Демонстрация:

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            iterLeft--;
            if (iterLeft<= 0) {
                System.out.print("Action finished\n");
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Action progress: %d/%d\n", iterLeft, iterations);
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer();
    iterLeft = iterations;
    timer.schedule(task, 0, period/iterations);
```